# compact operator in a sense of unit sphere

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I want to prove that if $T$ is an operator and $\overline {T(unit~sphere)}$ is compact, then T is compact i.e. $\overline {T(unit~ball)}$ is compact.

Suppose that $(a_n)$ is a bounded sequence in closed unit ball and $b_n:=\dfrac{a_n}{||a_n||}$. Then  $Tb_n=\dfrac{Ta_n}{||a_n||}$. Then there exists a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ such that $Tb_{n_k}$ convergent. how can I prove that T is compact?

Every hint is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe $T$ is bounded/continuous?

Comment: Our assumption is that  $T$ is bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $Tb_n \in T(\text{unit sphere})$, there is a convergent subsequence $(Tb_{n_k})_k$. Now note that $\|a_{n_k}\| \in [0,1]$ which is compact, so there exists another subsequence of this subsequence, let's call it $\|a_{m_k}\|$, that converges. Now we have that $Ta_{m_k} = \|a_{m_k}\| Tb_{n_k}$ converges, since it is a product of converging sequences. So we have found our converging subsequence.